# (MAC) Command and SH files won't run when started from app in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, mono, usb

So I have this USB button I am trying to make mute my computer and minimize all the windows.

I have a mute.command file that does this perfectly. If I double click it, it mutes the computer and minimizes everything.

I also tried making it a .sh file. This too works when executed normally.

The USB button has proprietary software, but some people made an alternative customizable version here: http://dreamcheekyusb.codeplex.com/discussions/397792

Anyway, I got mono working to run the .exe file, got it connected to the button, and even tested it out by getting the button to open up a video file on press.

When I try to get it to open up a command or sh file, though, nothing happens. The terminal pauses for a second and then continues on working.

Is there something I'm missing?

Also, the button .exe file outputs 'Detected button press event' when it is pressed. Is there a way to programmatically check the terminal to see when that phrase appears, and when it happens trigger commands? I'm thinking maybe the whole exe through mono thing is making it difficult to execute commands.

Or, is there a way to treat commands as a regular file? It will open the video file no problem. I tried setting the default program for .sh files to terminal, but it still isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your terminal have to do with the button presses? Are you manually running the executable in a terminal window that you leave open/running? How did you configure it to play the video? How do you have it configured to run your script?

Comment: I have a startbutton.command file that contains :

`export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/:${PATH}

mono Documents/btn/btn.exe CMD=./Documents/btn/mute.sh`

I start that and it keeps open and running in the background, minimized.
So the terminal start the btn.exe program in mono and goes from there.

The CMD argument is apparently supposed to be the command run, but it also opens files. I just put the file name for the video in there and when I pressed the button it opened up.

Comment: Is the `mute.sh` script set executable? Does it have a shebang (`#!`) line at the top? Does it work without an interactive shell session (can you run `bash /path/to/Documents/btn/mute.sh`)? Does using a full path to the script in the file help?

Comment: Yes it is executable, Yes it has the shebang, yes it runs without and interactive shell session, and no - a full path yields the same result.

Comment: Does `./path/to/Documents/btn/mute.sh` work in your shell? Can you click on the script and have it run correctly? (You said you have a `mute.command` file that works that way. Is that the `mute.sh` script?)

Comment: Yes, yes, and I have both. They're almost identical, the .command and the .sh.

I figured out another way of doing what I want, as my answer below states. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't do exactly what I wanted, but I ended up saving an applescript as an .app file and the btn will open that. The button software seems to not work well with scripts, but will open regular files and apps.